# Different alignment for table number and caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, captions

I have a table whose table number should be right-aligned and its caption should be center-aligned on the next line like this:

```
                          Table 1
           Caption
---------------------------------
|    |       |        |         |
---------------------------------
```

I found the `caption` package which is a powerful tool for changing caption styles, but it doesn't allow to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, you may declare a new format that will add `\hfill` at the very start of the caption (hereby making its first line raggedright).

(In the following example, I also use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to center the tabular material and to allow switching the caption's position from below to above.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{hfillstart}{\hfill#1#2#3\par}
\captionsetup[table]{format=hfillstart,labelsep=newline,justification=centering}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\newcommand{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\begin{document}

This is normal text. \sometext

\begin{table}
(Tabular material)
\caption{This is a table caption. \sometext}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that loading `floatrow` just to avoid `\centering` is exaggerated. :)

Comment: @egreg It also allows to switch the caption's position. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep many thanks! it works like a charm! :)

Comment: @martemiev You're welcome -- and don't forget to accept my answer. ;-)