# Changing style of table caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, captions

I'm using the `\caption` command inside `\begin{table}` command and in the output I'm getting:

```
Table 4.1 - Caption
    Table Content
```

Is it possible to change that style to something like this?

```
                    *Table 4.1*
    **Caption**
   Table Content
```

The word "Table" and its number should be at the right side of page and in italic, the caption should be centered and bold.

PS

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{hfillstart}{\hfill#1#2#3\par}
\captionsetup[table]{format=hfillstart,labelsep=newline,justification=centering}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
```

I have used this code from link below. How to change it to make Table italic, and caption bold?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: See the [caption2 package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption2) for such customisations.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78774/different-alignment-for-table-number-and-caption

Comment: @AndrewSwann The `caption2` package is obsolete. One should use `caption` or `floatrow`; the latter builds upon the former.

Comment: @egreg You are perfectly right - a few years ago it used to be the other way around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{hfillstart}{\hfill#1#2#3\par}
\DeclareCaptionFont{mdit}{\mdseries\itshape}
\captionsetup[table]{
  format=hfillstart,
  labelsep=newline,
  justification=centering,
  font=bf,
  labelfont=mdit,
}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
```

I'm not too much convinced about boldface captions, though.

Comment: It's not necessary to declare a new `mdit` font; simply use the `labelfont` and `textfont` keys.

Comment: @lockstep Right, but it may be useful to have also this possibility, so the two parts can share some setting.

Comment: what do `#1#2#3` in `\DeclareCaptionFormat{hfillstart}{\hfill#1#2#3\par}` refer to?

Comment: @Viesturs The package documentation specifies that `#1` refers to the caption label, `#2` to the separator and `#3` to the caption text.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me whether your "Table italic"  refers to the "Table XXX" label in the table's caption or to the body of the table:

- In the first case, add `labelfont=it,textfont=bf` to the argument of `\captionsetup`.
- In the second case, add `font=bf` to the argument of `\captionsetup` and `font=it` to the argument of `\floatsetup`.

See section 2.3 of the `caption` manual and section 3.1.2 of the `floatrow` manual for details.