# Table Caption spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, apa7

I´m trying to format my tables according to APA7, thus i need extra space in the caption.

I tried to apply a solution proposed in this post: [Table caption spacing in dissertation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191250/table-caption-spacing-in-dissertation)

But sadly it didn´t work.

The output i would need looks like this:

[image: Correct caption output]

However the output i get looks like this:

[image: My table with wrong caption]

Unfortunately i´m not able to add the correct spacing in the tables. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Find attached a MWE

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=apa, datelabel=comp, uniquelist=minyear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit_memes.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{twolines}{\newline\newline}

\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=twolines,
    textfont=it,
    singlelinecheck=off,
    aboveskip=0pt
}

\begin{document}
    \input{Text-Ab}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\tiny
\caption{Übersicht über das Kategoriensystem (Hauptkategorien)}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Forschungsfrage & Hauptkategorien & Beispiel-Ausprägungen \\ \midrule
A               & B               & C                     \\
D               & E               & F                    
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

    \clearpage
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use APA7 document class?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, i tried to set it up using the ```apa7``` document class, but unfortunately it produces unnumbered headings (my university requires numbered headings) and numerous package errors, so i think this document class won´t work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do more or less what you want, methinks:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=apa, datelabel=comp, uniquelist=minyear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit_memes.bib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linktoc = all, draft = false, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{twolines}{\medskip\newline}

\captionsetup[table]{
    format =plain,
    labelsep=twolines,
    labelfont=bf,
    textfont=it,
    singlelinecheck=off,
    aboveskip=0pt,
    belowskip=2.5ex
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\tiny
\caption{Übersicht über das Kategoriensystem (Hauptkategorien)}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Forschungsfrage & Hauptkategorien & Beispiel-Ausprägungen \\ \midrule
A & B & C \\
D & E & F
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]